# Java Login method: runs if details are correct but NullPointerException if incorrect

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've written a method to check an inputed username and password with a text file with all the usernames and passwords.  The interesting problem is that if the details are correct then the application progresses, but if the details are incorrect it returns a NullPointerException.  My code is below:

```
// Checks whether the inputed details are correct
public boolean isCorrect(String u, String p) {
    boolean check = false;
    String line = null;
    try {
        do {
            line = br.readLine();
            // System.out.println("Checking profile : " + line);
            String[] info = line.split("\t");
            // nested if-statement to improve efficiency over &&
            if (info[0].equals(u)) {
                System.out.println("username found!");
                if (info[1].equals(p)) {
                    System.out.println("password correct!");
                    check = true;
                } else System.out.println("password incorrect!");
            } else System.out.println("username not found!");
        } while (line != null && check == false);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return check;
}
```

The returned boolean value is entered into the following code in the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpanel); 
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            Correct = false;



    lm = new LoginModel(this);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText textUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
            EditText textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);

            // Collect the login details entered by the user
            String username = textUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = textPassword.getText().toString();

            // Check the application is registering the correct details
            System.out.println(username + "\n" + password);

            Correct = lm.isCorrect(username, password);

            if (Correct) { // if details are correct then start main program
                Intent intent = new Intent (LoginView.this, MenuListView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else System.out.println("Login is incorrect...");
        }
    });
}
```

What I don't understand is why if Correct = true then it runs no problems, but if Correct = false it crashes the program producing a FATAL EXCEPTION: main, and then a NullPointerException - shouldn't it simply output the the System.out.println.

Comment: _Do not store passwords in plain text_.  **Especially not on the client**

Comment: You haven't shown where the NullPointerException is actually occurring - what does the stack trace show?

Comment: `// nested if-statement to improve efficiency over &&`  Wrong.  `&&` is short-circuiting.

Comment: can you include the stacktrace, and the line it is pointing to?

Comment: How do I provide a formatted stacktrace?  When I copy it loses its structure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get to the end of the file, `line` is `null`.
Therefore, you can't call `split()` in the nest line (pun intended).

However, **do not use this code**.  It is very wrong and will trivially leak passwords once released.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the error is SLaks - I'll rewrite the code bearing in mind what everyone has said!

Comment: Instead, use salted hashes on a secure private server.